# get the level of current row in recursive or linked list like table ,

Tags: php, mysql

my table contain the following fields 
code , name , upper_code 
I can use code value in upper code field and so on, is there a way to query which level is deep the row with code I choose , I use this table to record financial chart of accounts

Comment: Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 0):

A loop that keeps on searching until upper_code is null or not found. You can do that in PHP or in a stored procedure.

There are alternatives but require that you change the structure of your database.